# How to senk keys to a element like <textarea id="description" wrap="virtual"/>

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have below element

```
<textarea id="description" class="textarea long-field wiki-textfield long-field mentionable" name="description" rows="12" data-projectkey="TST" data-issuekey="TST-4790" resolved="" wrap="virtual"/>
```

usually i send input values using below code, but for above element it is not possible. what could be the reason for this?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comment']")).sendKeys("test input");
```

thank you in-advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your id is `description` not `comment`

Try with id as `description`, if still not work use below XPath

```
//textarea[@id='description' and @name='description' and @class='textarea long-field wiki-textfield long-field mentionable' and @wrap='virtual']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: udpated answer with wrap. If you donot require class name remove it

Answer (score 1):

The `HTML` you shared contains the `id` and `name` both the locators which makes our task easy but they are within the `<textarea>` tag. So we can easily locate the `WebElement` through any of the `xpath` mentioned below and invoke the `sendKeys()` method as follows:

- XPATH using `id`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='description']")).sendKeys("test input1");
  ```
- XPATH using `name`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='description']")).sendKeys("test input2");
  ```